# Do we need to modify a script to be able to use the timeline visualization of CommaIDE

Tags: raku, commaide

I am running a concurrent script from CommaIDE, and it shows only "Waiting for timeline data" while the status line shows "Timeline connection error: Could not get timeline data: java.net.ConnectException: refused connection"
Is there any additional configuration I need to do somewhere?
Here's the error in the Event Log:

```
11:05   Timeline connection error: Could not get timeline data: java.net.ConnectException: Conexión rehusada
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any additional configuration I need to do somewhere?

If there are no issues with networking, you still need to setup your project according to the `Log::Timeline` module readme (https://github.com/jnthn/p6-log-timeline) for Comma to be able to gather the data you provide for logging.