# "Could not get Timeline data" when using Timeline Visualization with Comma IDE

Tags: raku, commaide

After implementing the answer to [this question on how to set up a script for time visualization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58428899/do-we-need-to-modify-a-script-to-be-able-to-use-the-timeline-visualization-of-co) in [this project](https://github.com/geneura-papers/2020-evostar-concurrent-eas/blob/master/code/concurrent-ea-leading-ones.p6) (which uses a small extension to the published `Log::Timeline` that allows me to set the logging file from the program itself), I still get the same error

```
12:18   Timeline connection error: Could not get timeline data: java.net.ConnectException: Conexión rehusada
```

(which means refused connection). I've also checked the created files, and they are empty, they don't receive anything. I'm using this to log:

```
class Events does Log::Timeline::Event['ConcurrentEA', 'App', 'Log'] { }
```

(as per [the README.md file](https://github.com/JJ/p6-log-timeline/blob/master/README.md)). It's probably the case that there's no such thing as a default implementation, as shown in the [tests](https://github.com/jnthn/p6-log-timeline/blob/master/t/logging.t), but, in that case, what would be the correct way of making it print to the file and also connect to the timeline visualizer?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the timeline visualization, leave the defaults for logging, commenting out any modification of the standard logging output. In my case:

```
#BEGIN {
#    PROCESS::<$LOG-TIMELINE-OUTPUT>
#           = Log::Timeline::Output::JSONLines.new(
#               path => log-file
#            )
#}
```

[image: Timeline event visualization]

Not really sure if this would have happened if an output file is defined using an environment variable, but in any case, better to be on the safe side. You can use the output file when you eventually drop the script into production.

Comment: Did you find setting `PROCESS::<$LOG-TIMELINE-OUTPUT>` documented somewhere? That's considered an implementation detail. If you really want to include something in your script, then poke into `%*ENV` at `BEGIN` time instead, in order to use a supported interface.

Comment: @JonathanWorthington I used the usual motto "If it's in the source code, it's documented". But OK, that's another way to go.