# Task logging (apparently) not working in Comma IDE using Log::Timeline

Tags: logging, raku, commaide

After [I got to see the actual timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58521249/could-not-get-timeline-data-when-using-timeline-visualization-with-comma-ide), now it's time to try and run tasks and log them. I'm using again a default configuration for a task logger, and calling it [with](https://github.com/geneura-papers/2020-evostar-concurrent-eas/blob/5cd3f5a71cc8e64fe107c5306050f20ee68d9368/code/concurrent-ea-leading-ones.p6#L55-L56):

```
my $promise = start react whenever $channel-one -> @crew {
            Algorithm::Evolutionary::LogTimelineSchema::Evolutionary.log: {
```

That is, the logging schema is called whenever a particular thread activates itself. Tasks are defined in Algorithm::Evolutionary::LogTimelineSchema this way:

```
class Evolutionary does Log::Timeline::Task['ConcurrentEA', 'Concurrent',
        'Evolutionary'] { }

class Mixer does Log::Timeline::Task['ConcurrentEA', 'Concurrent',
        'Mixer'] { }
```

However, I don't see the task logging appearing anywhere in the timeline. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

*Update*: Adds code for the task loggers

Comment: What does the definition of `Algorithm::Evolutionary::LogTimelineSchema::Evolutionary` look like?

Comment: @JonathanWorthington updates with code.

Comment: i believe the timeline display in comma doesn't display scroll bars; can you try scrolling sideways (by dragging IIRC) or scrolling (with the mousewheel; not sure if a modifier like shift or ctrl is needed additionally)

Comment: @timotimo I'm not sure what you mean here. I also have simple event logging, and task logging should appear at pretty much the same time, but nothing shows up.